# Aws Ec2 instance stops automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been kinda frustated by this thing for hours.I have 2 Ec2 instances which use aws educate for billing.And whenever I start them both of them stop automatically once aws logged in session is over.Do anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are they part of an Auto Scaling group? There is no concept of a "logged in session" in AWS, but I know that AWS Educate accounts do strange things to reduce costs. To discover the truth, you can look in the AWS CloudTrail logs and looks for API calls that stop (terminate?) the instances. They will provide information about what credentials were used for the API call, which can help you track down what is happening. You can also ask the AWS Educate team at: https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/

Comment: Nope I don't have any autoscaling groups.I will check the logs,thanks